# Is seeds.rb a noun or verb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding

In `Rails`, in the `db` directory, we have a file called `seeds.rb`.

["To add initial data after a database is created, Rails has a built-in 'seeds' feature that makes the process quick and easy."](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data)

Does anybody know if the wording is choosen as "it *seeds* the database".

Or is the word meant as the plural form of seed, i.e. "to plant multiple seeds into the database"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, it's a noun.

One of the naming conventions considers two options: a command (`seed` it) or a query (`seeds`). It helps straighten out the intention of the file. In Ruby on Rails we have a **command** (a verb): `rake db:seed` that gets the information about how to perform the seeding with data from a **query**: `db/seeds.rb`.

Again - only my opinion

Comment: I can agree that the file itself is a noun how every the act of running it would be a verb in my opinion. I have `seeds` (my seeds.rb file) that I wish to `seed` (the act of seeding or sowing). Just as I have a shovel that I can shovel with, I have seeds that I can seed with.

Comment: @engineersmnky Hmm, I believe i didn't make myself clear enough, because this is exactly what I meant :) I edited the answer